# Tensorflow (object detection api) keeps blocking RAM after inference

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, jupyter-lab

After I make an inference on a loaded image, tensorflow keeps blocking the RAM (~ 2GB). It doesn't free it up even after the execution is finished.

I did transfer learning on the coco dataset with my own images and use jupyter lab for the final inference of the images. I oriented myself at an [adapted version](https://github.com/RomRoc/objdet_train_tensorflow_colab/pull/7) of [RomRoc's Dog Detector](https://hackernoon.com/object-detection-in-google-colab-with-custom-dataset-5a7bb2b0e97e). The model itself (*frozen_inference_graph*) has a size of around 50MB.

I am using *JupyterLab version 0.35.5* on *Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon*. My RAM is only 4 GB which often leads to crashes for multiple inferences. SWAP storage is activated and used.

I checked the size of all variables using the variable inspector, but they are just a fraction of the 2 GB used.

I suspect that the session or graph are not closed correctly, but even the manual closing doesn't lead to freeing up memory.

This is the code leading to a big increase in RAM usage:

```
def run_inference_for_single_image(image, graph):
    with graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            # Get handles to input and output tensors
            ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
            all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
            tensor_dict = {}
            for key in ['num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
                        'detection_classes', 'detection_masks']:
                tensor_name = key + ':0'
                if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                    tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)

            if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
                # The following processing is only for single image
                detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
                detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])

                # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
                real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
                detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
                detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
                detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(detection_masks, detection_boxes, 
                                                                                      image.shape[0], image.shape[1])
                detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(
                tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
                # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
                tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(detection_masks_reframed, 0)

            image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

            # Run inference
            output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict, feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})

            # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
            output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
            output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
            output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
            output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
            if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
                output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]
    return output_dict
```

I expect memory consumption going back to the normal usage level of ~ 400 MB, like before the inference. Thanks already for any advices.

---

I could replicate the same problem for [the official tensorflow object detection tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). Although this one is actually less memory hungry.

Comment: The variables you checked belong to the code you mentioned above. Did you consider all the processes, temporary value generated and variables in the files your mentioned code depend on? (Variables in imported files). Inference is complex procedure which will require a good amount of memory.

Comment: I took the code from the function and ran it for checking the variable sizes. There were no large variables inside. I think it must be due to the process, but then I don't understand why it keeps the RAM even after finishing.
As far as I understand it, only the `tf.session` will fill the graph with actual numbers. But shouldn't it be closed with the end of the `with` statement?